# How to convert a set of probabilities to a value between 0 and 1?

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, mathematical-modeling

I need to make a function which output a value between 0 and 1 which specifies the quality of the quantity I am measuring (0 is bad quality and 1 is high quality).
The input to this function are 3 probability values which vary from 0 and 1. The first probability value says the goodness of my measurement and second and third probability values are the correct measurement rate and wrong measurement rate. I need to use this information (probabilities) to make a model/function that gives the current quality of my model. So how to normalise these 3 probabilities to a value between 0 and 1. Any hints would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is using [generalized (power) mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PowerMean.html). It is an appropriate solution if your $3$ values are (almost) equally significant. Be aware that for negative power this mean has problem with zeros.

Another way is using [weighted mean](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeightedMean.html). In this case you can give weights according to values significance.

Also it is possible to combine both ideas.